# Spring JDBC - Passing in ARRAY of BLOBs to SQL Function

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to pass in an `ARRAY` of `BLOB`s, but I am getting errors.

```
uploadFiles = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withCatalogName("FILES_PKG")
                    .withFunctionName("insertFiles").withReturnValue()
                    .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("p_userId", Types.NUMERIC),
                            new SqlParameter("p_data", Types.ARRAY, "BLOB_ARRAY"),
                            new SqlOutParameter("v_groupId", Types.NUMERIC));
uploadFiles.compile();
List<Blob> fileBlobs = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int x = 0; x < byteFiles.size(); x++){
            fileBlobs.add(new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(byteFiles.get(x)));
        }

        final Blob[] data = fileBlobs.toArray(new Blob[fileBlobs.size()]);

        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("p_files", new SqlArrayValue<Blob>(data, "BLOB_ARRAY"))
                .addValue("p_userId", userId);

        Map<String, Object> results = uploadFiles.execute(in);
```

I created a SQL Type in the DB

```
create or replace TYPE BLOB_ARRAY is table of BLOB;
```

Function Spec

```
 FUNCTION insertFiles(p_userId IN NUMBER,
                p_files IN BLOB_ARRAY)
      RETURN NUMBER;
```

Function Body

```
FUNCTION insertFiles (p_userId IN NUMBER,
                       p_files IN BLOB_ARRAY)
      RETURN NUMBER
   AS

      v_groupId NUMBER := FILE_GROUP_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
      v_fileId NUMBER;
   BEGIN

      FOR i IN 1..p_files.COUNT
      LOOP

      v_fileId := FILE_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL;
      BEGIN
      INSERT INTO FILES
      (FILE_ID,
       FILE_GROUP_ID,
       FILE_DATA,
       UPDT_USER_ID)
       SELECT
       v_fileId,
       v_groupId,
       p_files(i),
       USER_ID
       FROM USERS 
       WHERE USER_ID = p_userId;
       EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
       v_groupId := -1;
      END;

      END LOOP;

      RETURN v_groupId;
   END insertFiles;
```

I am not sure how to correctly pass the array of Blobs to the SQL Function.

Error :

> java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation:
>   javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob@87829c90   at
>   oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeBLOB.toDatum(OracleTypeBLOB.java:69)
>   ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.1.0]  at
>   oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleType.toDatumArray(OracleType.java:176)
>   ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.1.0]  at
>   oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor.toOracleArray(ArrayDescriptor.java:1321)
>   ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.1.0]  at oracle.sql.ARRAY.(ARRAY.java:140)
>   ~[ojdbc7.jar:12.1.0.1.0]  at

**UPDATE**

After trying Luke's suggestion, I am getting the following error:

> uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call FILES_PKG.INSERTFILES(?,
>   ?)}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [22922]; ORA-22922: nonexistent
>   LOB value ; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22922:
>   nonexistent LOB value ] with root cause
>
> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-22922: nonexistent LOB value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message appears to indicate the Oracle JDBC driver doesn't know what to do with the javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob object you've passed to it.

Try creating the `Blob` objects using [`Connection.createBlob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob()) instead.  In other words, try replacing the following 
loop

```
        for(int x = 0; x < byteFiles.size(); x++){
            fileBlobs.add(new javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob(byteFiles.get(x)));
        }
```

with

```
        Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        for(int x = 0; x < byteFiles.size(); x++){
            Blob blob = conn.createBlob();
            blob.setBytes(1, byteFiles.get(x));
            fileBlobs.add(blob);
        }
```

Also, make sure that your parameter names are consistent between your `SimpleJdbcCall` and your stored function.   Your `SimpleJdbcCall` declares the `BLOB` array parameter with name `p_data` but your stored function declaration uses `p_files`.  If the parameter names are not consistent you are likely to get an `Invalid column type` error.

However, had I run the above test with a stored function of my own that actually did something with the `BLOB` values passed in, instead of just hard-coding a return value, I might have found that this approach didn't work.  I'm not sure why, I'd probably have to spend some time digging around in the guts of Spring to find out.

I tried replacing the `Blob` values with Spring `SqlLobValue`s, but that didn't work either.  I guess Spring's `SqlArrayValue<T>` type doesn't handle Spring wrapper objects for various JDBC types.

So I gave up on a Spring approach and went back to plain JDBC:

```
import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;

// ...

        OracleConnection conn = dataSource.getConnection().unwrap(OracleConnection.class);

        List<Blob> fileBlobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int x = 0; x < byteFiles.size(); x++){
            Blob blob = conn.createBlob();
            blob.setBytes(1, byteFiles.get(x));
            fileBlobs.add(blob);
        }

        Array array = conn.createOracleArray("BLOB_ARRAY",
            fileBlobs.toArray(new Blob[fileBlobs.size()]));

        CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{? = call insertFiles(?, ?)}");
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.NUMERIC);
        cstmt.setInt(2, userId);
        cstmt.setArray(3, array);

        cstmt.execute();

        int result = cstmt.getInt(1);
```

I've tested this with the stored function you've now included in your question, and it is able to call this function and insert the `BLOB`s into the database.

I'll leave it up to you to do what you see fit with the variable `result` and to add any necessary cleanup or transaction control.

However, while this approach *worked*, it didn't feel *right*.  It didn't fit the Spring way of doing things.  It did at least prove that what you were asking for was possible, in that there wasn't some limitation in the JDBC driver that meant you couldn't use `BLOB` arrays.  I felt that there ought to be some way to call your function using Spring JDBC.

I spent some time looking into the ORA-22922 error and concluded that the underlying problem was that the `Blob` objects were being created using a different `Connection` to what was being used to execute the statement.  The question then becomes how to get hold of the `Connection` Spring uses.

After some further digging around in the source code to various Spring classes, I realised that a more Spring-like way of doing this is to replace the `SqlArrayValue<T>` class with a different one specialised for `BLOB` arrays.  This is what I ended up with:

```
import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection;
import org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.support.AbstractSqlTypeValue;

public class SqlBlobArrayValue extends AbstractSqlTypeValue {

    private List<byte[]> values;

    private String defaultTypeName;

    public SqlBlobArrayValue(List<byte[]> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public SqlBlobArrayValue(List<byte[]> values, String defaultTypeName) {
        this.values = values;
        this.defaultTypeName = defaultTypeName;
    }

    protected Object createTypeValue(Connection conn, int sqlType, String typeName)
            throws SQLException {
        if (typeName == null && defaultTypeName == null) {
            throw new InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException(
                    "The typeName is null in this context. Consider setting the defaultTypeName.");
        }

        Blob[] blobs = new Blob[values.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < blobs.length; ++i) {
            Blob blob = conn.createBlob();
            blob.setBytes(1, values.get(i));
            blobs[i] = blob;
        }

        Array array = conn.unwrap(OracleConnection.class).createOracleArray(typeName != null ? typeName : defaultTypeName, blobs);
        return array;
    }
}
```

This class is heavily based on [`SqlArrayValue<T>`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc-ext/blob/master/spring-data-oracle/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/support/oracle/SqlArrayValue.java), which is licensed under [Version 2 of the Apache License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).  For brevity, I've omitted comments and a `package` directive.

With the help of this class, it becomes a lot easier to call your function using Spring JDBC.  In fact, you can replace everything after the call to `uploadFiles.compile()` with the following:

```
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("p_files", new SqlBlobArrayValue(byteFiles, "BLOB_ARRAY"))
                .addValue("p_userId", userId);

        Map<String, Object> results = uploadFiles.execute(in);
```

Comment: thank you for the response, I updated my question. I seem to have run into another error when creating the `BLOB` with the `Connection`. I also made the parameter names consistent.

Comment: @Alan: sorry about your code still returning an error.  That's probably my fault for not bothering to write a proper stored function to test against!  I've edited my answer to add a 'plain' JDBC approach which works for me, in that I can use it to call your function.

Comment: Thank you! I have been banging my head against this problem for a couple days and have been trying to do it the "Spring" way and this seems to work just fine.

Comment: @Alan: should you be interested, I've managed to come up with a more Spring-like approach to calling your function.  I've edited my answer to include it.

Comment: that is awesome! Thank you for the update. :) I will probably end up using the Springy way